# Is a non-meagre set comeagre in its closure?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Let $A$ be a non-meagre subset of a topological space $X$. Is $A$ comeagre in its closure $\mathcal{Cl}(A)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let $A$ be a [Bernstein set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set) in $\Bbb R$. $A$ and $\Bbb R\setminus A$ are dense in $\Bbb R$ and non-meagre. In fact, [both are Baire spaces](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/bernstein-set/).

Answer (score 3):

No.  Work in $\mathbb R$, and let $X$ be $\left((0,1)\cap\mathbb Q\right)\cup(1,2)$, so $X$ is nonmeagre (because of its right half) but non-co-meagre in its closure (because of its left half).